# Windows domain list users details where password never expires

Tags: powershell, password, adsi

I have a Windows domain, where I need to find users with option to never expire password enabled - as a part of an audit and for contacting them. I have no rights to install any fancy Powershell parts or nothing else on the servers. I suspect adsisearcher through Powershell could probably do the trick.I also need the contact info, like email address (there are multiple addresses for many users, not sure whether that changes anything). As well there are many not real user accounts, which could unnecessarily inflate my list of users to contact.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`userAccountControl` bit for controlling "Password never expires"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144#mt1) is `0x10000` (65536 in decimal).

The following LDAP filter will return all users with the option set:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))
```

With an `adsisearcher` that would become something like:

```
$Searcher = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))'
$PwdNeverExpireUsers = $Searcher.FindAll()
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to my actual question, thanks buddy :)